# Prevent cl.exe from printing the compiled source file

Tags: visual-studio, command-line

I use the MS compiler from the command line (VS 2008), and whenever it compiles one source file, it prints the compiled source file. Is there a way to avoid this useless print ?

Comment: Is there still no way to do this? It's been ten years. I opened an issue here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/717761/allow-having-clexe-not-print-the-compiled-source-f.html

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There's no way to suppress that message with a switch (see also [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vclanguage/thread/9eabed6b-8bae-4c86-a8d8-c7fc2c8e6ed2)).

Comment: I was afraid this was not possible. Thanks for the confirmation

Comment: You could suppress the message using `cl ... > nil`. But I'm not sure thats a good idea since it will also suppress compiler errors.

Comment: Is there still no way to do this? It's been ten years. I opened an issue here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/717761/allow-having-clexe-not-print-the-compiled-source-f.html

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're using the /E switch which prints the source to the std output after it's run through the preprocessor.