# How to filter output from cl.exe but preserve success/error code?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line-tool

Related to: [Prevent cl.exe from printing the compiled source file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453767/prevent-cl-exe-from-printing-the-compiled-source-file)

I want to filter out the ".cpp" from the compiler output, but not filter out any compiler errors. I can do this:

`cl -nologo source.cpp | findstr /V /X "source.cpp"`

But this has 2 problems:

1. If the only line of output from the compiler is the filename, the `findstr` returns a failure code.
2. The errorlevel from the `cl.exe` call is lost.

I could fix the first problem without too much trouble, but I'm not sure how to tackle the second problem without using a temporary file (which I'd like to avoid!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a temporary file in this case might be a better choice to avoid over complicating the code.

However if you really need to avoid temporary file, then you can obtain cl's `errorlevel` inside the pipe but then to capture the value and use it inside your main code, you need to use `FOR /F` in order to capture both the findstr's output and cl's `errorlevel`.

Obtaining the `errorlevel` value inside a pipe is tricky enough by itself, because the pipe's child cmd will expand `%errorlevel%` before invoking `cl`, And It will get more tricky when pipe's child cmd is nested inside the `FOR /F`'s child cmd.

```
@echo off
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion

set "errorlevel="
set "_errorlevel=errorlevel"
set "__errorlevel=_errorlevel"
for /F "delims=" %%A in ('
    ^( cl -nologo source.cpp ^& call echo ###cl_errorlevel:%%%%%%__errorlevel%%%%%% ^) ^| findstr /V /X "source.cpp"
    ') do (

    set "cl_out=%%A"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    if "!cl_out:~0,17!"=="###cl_errorlevel:" (
        endlocal

        REM delims is set to <colon> and <space>
        REM <space> is used to remove trailing the space(s) in echo's output which is unavoidable
        REM Alternatively <nul set /p "=Output_String" can be used to eliminate the need to use <space> as delimeter
        for /F "tokens=2 delims=: " %%B in ("%%A") do set "cl_errorlevel=%%B"
    ) else (
        endlocal
        REM cl's output, filtered by findstr
        echo(%%A
    )
)
echo,
echo cl_errorlevel:%cl_errorlevel%
pause
```

I used the string `###cl_errorlevel:` for it to be unique enough to be distinguishable from the rest the cl's output.

The `errorlevel` from findstr should not matter, you can just act upon `cl_errorlevel`

---

**UPDATE**
I took [aschipfl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5047996/aschipfl)'s excellent advice from the comments, to not use the `###cl_errorlevel` prefix, and reimplemented the code in a much more simpler way, which solely relays on the fact that `errorlevel` from `cl` is the last line that returned by `FOR /F`

```
@echo off
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion

set "errorlevel="
set "_errorlevel=errorlevel"
set "__errorlevel=_errorlevel"
set "line="
for /F "delims=" %%A in ('
    ^( cl -nologo source.cpp ^& call set /p "=%%%%%%__errorlevel%%%%%%"^<nul ^) ^| findstr /V /X "source.cpp"
    ') do (
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    echo(!line!
    endlocal
    set "line=%%A"  
)
set "cl_errorlevel=%line%"

echo,
echo cl_errorlevel:%cl_errorlevel%
pause
```

There will be an additional empty line in the beginning of the the `cl` output which I don't see it as an unwanted thing, But if it is really needed to be removed, then it can be done with an `IF` statement like this:

```
if defined line (
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    echo(!line!
    endlocal
)
```

Comment: That is impressive. Indeed it's a little overcomplicated just to avoid writing a temp file, but thanks!

Comment: Nice! Getting the `ErrorLevel` could be a bit simpler though: `for /F "delims=" %%A in ('^(cl -nologo source.cpp ^^^& call echo ###cl_errorlevel:%%^^^^^^ErrorLevel%%^) ^| findstr /V /X "source.cpp"') do ( ... )`. Also you would not need the `###cl_errorlevel` prefix as you do know that the `ErrorLevel` is the *last* line returned...

Comment: @aschipfl, Many thanks for taking time reviewing my answer. If it can be guaranteed that both `^^^ErrorLevel` and `^ErrorLevel` are undefined - which is the case most the time anyway - indeed it is simpler. (I think there is no need for extra escaping the ampersand (`^^^&`), it will not be parsed in a parenthesized pipe block). Regarding `###cl_errorlevel` and the fact that `errorlevel` is returned on the last line, I echoed `%cl_errorlevel%` just for demonstrating the result, but I don't have a clue how to determine if I'm reading the last line without it being printed on screen.

Comment: @aschipfl, I've updated the answer based on your comment. Thank you!

Comment: @MattChambers, You may want to check the updated answer.

Comment: Perfect, that is exactly what I was thinking of to get the last line!